# How to remove custom text in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$("p:nth-of-type(2)").click(function() {
var textarea = $("textarea");
textarea.val.remove("p:nth-of-type(2)");
});
```

```html
<textarea>
<p>My text.</p>
<p>Text for remove</p>
<p>My text.</p>
</textarea>
<p>My text.</p>
<p>Text for remove</p>
<p>My text.</p>
```

How to remove "p:nth-of-type(2)" in textarea?
My javascript code does not working!

Comment: A paragraph (and all html elements for that matter) ceases to exist inside a `textarea` and is treated like regular text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every html element will tranform into text inside textarea ...So you can't use dsudo select ...

I think you want to remove same element of clicked element , if so you can do by `replace` and compare by current clicked element value

```js
$("p:nth-of-type(2)").click(function() {
var textarea = $("textarea");
textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(this.outerHTML, ""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
<p>My text.</p>
<p>Text for remove</p>
<p>My text.</p>
</textarea>
<p>My text.</p>
<p>Text for remove</p>
<p>My text.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. But your code does not work in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nurzayvt/)

Comment: Because at the time click event is attach to document,  p element are still not loaded ! So you need to put that click function inside `document.ready` scope